# Is there a way to add tags for which browser protractor is testing to show on the report?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, reporting-services, protractor, cucumber

I'm using cucumber-reporting on jenkins https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting. I'm running parallel tests with different browsers. How can my report show which browser failed? Can I somehow add in tags like @firefox, @ie, @safari, @chrome to my features and how would I link them?

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  getPageTimeout: 600000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
  framework: 'custom',
  // path relative to the current config file
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  multiCapabilities:
  [
    {
      'browserName': 'safari'
    },
    {
      'browserName': 'internet explorer'
    },
  {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  }],

  // Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
  specs: [
    'features/*.feature'
  ],
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  ignoreSynchronization: true,
  cucumberOpts: {
    strict: true,
    require: [
              'hooks/reporter/js',
              'specs/*Spec.js'
            ],
    tags: ["runThis", "~ignoreThis"],
    profile: false,
    format: 'json:e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json',
    resultJsonOutputFile: 'e2e/reports/cucumber-report.json'
  },
  onPrepare: function() {

    var chai = require('chai');
    chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
    global.expect = chai.expect;
    global.baseURL = this.baseURL;
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.waitForAngular();           
    browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000);  
  },

  onComplete: function() {

    const report = require('multiple-cucumber-html-reporter');

    report.generate({
        jsonDir: 'e2e/reports/',
        reportPath: 'e2e/reports/',

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I never used multiCapabilities nor cucumber framework. But there is 'protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter' that can be used with jasmine. And it shows the browser name and version if `showConfiguration: true`

Comment: And another possibility for you to do what you're trying to do is pass browser name to reporter from your tests. You can get browser name like this `let capabilities = await browser.getCapabilities();
    let browserName = capabilities.map_.get('browserName');

    if (browserName === "chrome") {
        // do whatever
    }`